# Showing image from url with placeholder in UITextView with attributed string

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, ios8

I'm developing lib for markdown with swift and it works fine! But there is a little problem, when I load images that are in markdown I put placeholder image and dispatch another process to load original image, like this:

```
var attachment: NSTextAttachment = NSTextAttachment()

            attachment.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
            attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: attachment.image.size.width > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width ? CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/attachment.image.size.width * attachment.image.size.height)  : attachment.image.size )

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
                let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

                attachment.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: attachment.image.size.width > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width ? CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/attachment.image.size.width * attachment.image.size.height)  : attachment.image.size )
                self.textView.setNeedsDisplay()
            })

            let attributedString: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
            let lineBreak: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\n")

            self.markdown.deleteCharactersInRange(matchRange)

            self.markdown.insertAttributedString(attributedString, atIndex: matchRange.location)
            self.markdown.insertAttributedString(lineBreak, atIndex: matchRange.location)
```

but after loading image place holder doesn't disappear until user start to scroll, suddenly correct image shown!

So I am interested to know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change UI from global queue, it might not work. You may need to use the main queue for that like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
    let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // On the main queue (the main thread)
        attachment.image = image
        attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: attachment.image.size.width > UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width ? CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width/attachment.image.size.width * attachment.image.size.height)  : attachment.image.size )
        self.textView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
})
```

Comment: It's not work! just same as before when I start to scroll placeholder change to original image! do you have any other idea?

Comment: How about calling NSTextStorage -edited:range:changeInLength: method for self.textView textStorage object?

Comment: I could not use range, because other threads are working on markdown text and finding images link and remove them and insert image in place so this will cause to other range be wrong!

Comment: NSTextStorage is not thread safe. You must know what part of the textstorage would be modified at this point.